# COM Server libraries not registered by Installshield 2015/2018 Express

Tags: com, installshield, dllregistration

An installer project I have for my Delphi application used to work properly, in that it copied and registered the COM server DLL's correctly on the destination machine. This was built using *Installshield 2015 Express*.

Recent updates to Windows 10 for either the machine the installer is run on, or possibly the machine that I create the installer on, seems to have broken the COM Registration process.

Now when I build, it gives me a slew of these warning messages:

> ISEXP : warning -4354: The build was unable to extract COM information
>   from the file C:\InstallShield 2018 Projects\Current\Server
>   Libraries\COMServer.dll in component COMServer.dll. Please ensure that
>   the file is self-registering and verify that the self-registration
>   process does not fail.

After running the installer, by checking the registry, I can see that the COM server DLL's have not been registered as their CLSID information is missing. If I open an elevated command prompt and register the DLL's using **regsvr32**, they are then fine.

I've tried the "fixes" suggested, such as changing the compatibility of the IsCmdBld.exe, running IS as Administrator, turning on UAC (I never have it off).

One comment I saw said that we need to run a custom action after installation to run **regsvr32**, but I thought that was the whole point of the COM Registration step in the installer.

I also upgraded the project to *Installshield 2018 R2 Express* but have exactly the same problem.

Even as a licensed registered user, *Flexera* don't seem to be able to offer me any support, just pointing me to the community forums. I would prefer the SO community in that case.

Comment: This company always, always knows how to turn a user of their freebie product into a paying customer.  Resistance is futile.

Comment: @HansPassant. We were already a paying customer, but our 1 year silver support agreement expired, and we were not going to pay again if we were unsure they had resolved the problem. Turns out that was the right move. It's still broken in 2019, but there is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it is the version of *Windows* that **InstallShield** is installed on that causes the issue. Even the latest **InstallShield 2019 Professional** has the same problem with COM libraries.

On my *Windows 10 version 1903*, I get the errors as reported, but on a *Windows 7* or *Windows 10 version 1607* machine, no errors occur. It works with **InstallShield 2015**, **2018** and **2019**, both **Express** and **Professional** editions.

Obviously, Flexera need to get their act together with regard to assuming old versions of their programs (such as the `IsCmdBld.exe`) will work OK within the far more stringent security requirements of later versions of *Windows 10*.